# How route traffic with docker-compose app on ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, deployment, docker-compose, droplet

this is my first time that i try to make a simple deploy, so the procedure is not still clear.
This is what i have done:
For server i'm using a droplet from Digital Ocean.

1. I created a simple app in node, make a dockerfile and docker-compose.
   If i try to lunch "docker-compose up" in local everything is ok.
2. Then i pushed the project on github
3. I enstablished a ssh connection with my remote server, and pulled the project form github into the root folder.
4. I entered in the project folder and lunched "docker-compose up"

The command worked and everything is builed, but if i visit my IP, nothing is showed.
So, how can i route the traffic into the container builded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your containers are running correctly after `docker-compose up` command then you should be able to access the services with `{IP}:{PORT}`. How are the logs?

By the way, related with that, it is strongly recommended that you start your containers as services by running `docker stack deploy {your-stack-name}` so they can run in swarm mode, which is the right way to do it in production environment. More on that [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/#:%7E:text=When%20running%20Docker%20Engine%20in,version%20%E2%80%9C3.0%E2%80%9D%20or%20above)